# Bootstrap vue carousel component glitch

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

A weird bug occurs when I try to use `b-carousel` component with a source code from official docs. Looks like previous image turning grey during transition to the next one:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app'
})
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.21.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tether@2.0.0/dist/css/tether.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.13/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/tether@2.0.0/dist/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.21.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <b-carousel id="carousel-1" :interval="4000" controls indicators background="#ababab" img-width="1024" img-height="480" style="text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #333;">
    <!-- Text slides with image -->
    <b-carousel-slide caption="First slide" text="Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum." img-src="https://picsum.photos/1024/480/?image=52"></b-carousel-slide>

    <!-- Slides with custom text -->
    <b-carousel-slide img-src="https://picsum.photos/1024/480/?image=54">
      <h1>Hello world!</h1>
    </b-carousel-slide>

    <!-- Slides with image only -->
    <b-carousel-slide img-src="https://picsum.photos/1024/480/?image=58"></b-carousel-slide>

    <!-- Slides with img slot -->
    <!-- Note the classes .d-block and .img-fluid to prevent browser default image alignment -->
    <b-carousel-slide>
      <template #img>
          <img
            class="d-block img-fluid w-100"
            width="1024"
            height="480"
            src="https://picsum.photos/1024/480/?image=55"
            alt="image slot"
          >
        </template>
    </b-carousel-slide>

    <!-- Slide with blank fluid image to maintain slide aspect ratio -->
    <b-carousel-slide caption="Blank Image" img-blank img-alt="Blank image">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse eros felis, tincidunt a tincidunt eget, convallis vel est. Ut pellentesque ut lacus vel interdum.
      </p>
    </b-carousel-slide>
  </b-carousel>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSFiddle is importing `https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@next/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css` in the resources.
This is going to import Bootstrap version `5.0.0-beta3`.

Which is as issue as BootstrapVue only supports Bootstrap `4.3.1` to `4.5.3` (`4.5.3` being the recommended version).

So if you instead import `https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css`, it should work as intended.

https://jsfiddle.net/23ozwgnp/